# LINQ not causing insert trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, linq

Me again with another LINQ question.

Our database is set up so that there is an event trigger when an SQL insert occurs.

Now, this trigger is not being called when I am using LINQ. Is there something in particular I need to do to make the database see the LINQ command as an insert? (Code below). I should say that the data is being entered into the database correctly, but the trigger is not happening.

Thanks in advance.

LINQ code:

```
private void SaveToWebsure()
{
    using (MagTestDataContext context = new MagTestDataContext())
    {
        //create new instance of tblPolicy object
        tblPolicy policy = new tblPolicy();
        //generate PolicyID number
        policyNo = context.ExecuteQuery<int>("DECLARE @ret INT; EXEC spNextPolicyID @ret OUTPUT; SELECT @ret").Single();
        //add values to field
        policy.PolicyID = policyNo;
        policy.RecordType = "New Business";
        policy.SchemeID = 17;
        policy.Status = "Quote";
        policy.Title = ddTitle.Text + ' ' + tbSurname.Text;
        policy.PolicyHolder = ddTitle.Text + ' ' + tbFirstName.Text + ' ' + tbSurname.Text;
        policy.SearchKey = tbSurname.Text;
        policy.EMail = tbEmail.Text;
        policy.Telephone = tbTelephone.Text;
        policy.Address1 = tbAddressLine1.Text;
        policy.Address2 = tbAddressLine2.Text;
        policy.Address3 = tbAddressLine3.Text;
        policy.Address4 = tbAddressLine4.Text;
        policy.PostCode = tbPostcode.Text;
        policy.rowguid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        policy.Comments = "Current/Previous Insurer: " + tbInsurer.Text + "; " + "Reason for refused insurance: " + ddReason.SelectedItem.Text + "; " + "Further reasons specified: " + tbOther.Text;
        //insert new contact_detail object
        context.tblPolicies.InsertOnSubmit(policy);
        //submit changes to database
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

STORED PROCEDURE:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE spNextPolicyID @PolicyID int output AS
    begin tran

      /* update tblIdNumbers set ApplicantId = ApplicantId
      set @Policyid = (select ApplicantID from tblIdNumbers)
      update tblIdNumbers set ApplicantId = ApplicantId + 1 */
    set Rowcount 0
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    exec dbo.spNextIdNumber @PolicyID Output,'PolicyId'

    commit tran
```

Comment: Interesting. AFAIK linq doesn't do any magic. It simply creates an INSERT statment as part of a transaction. you could use a linq profiler to see the sql statements generated.

Comment: I thing you have to check your trigger not Linq

Comment: Stephen, any recommendations on a profiler? Glad to hear that it's not my code (for once!).

Comment: I showed the stored procedure to give you guys an idea of what the code is doing, not what the trigger is doing!

Comment: Can you show the trigger?

Comment: What database are you using. Are you sure that the trigger works properly?

Comment: I'll try to find it, I am new to the business and have not developed the triggers etc, so am still finding my feet. Please bear with me.

Comment: Ok the trigger is frigging massive, you sure you want it?

Comment: Don't include all, include the shell and the relevant parts.

Comment: As I said, I have not written the trigger personally and it is over 500 lines long so it is difficult for me to know what to present to you.

Comment: This doesn't seem as a LINQ problem, LINQ is just a wrapper for making easier to interact with queries. 
Try inserting manually in your database to see what's going on.

Comment: @matt5692 : test with a new and simple trigger and if not working you can write it to help you in this probleme

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the advice. I'll monitor the query and test if creating a new row, with only the necessary key and schemeid first, activates the trigger, and then I will update the row with the rest of the data.

Comment: If this is Linq to SQL then you can output the SQL by setting the Log property of your DataContext to Console.Out.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not doing anything special in the background. A couple of things you should check

- use SQL Profiler to see what query is being generated and what runs against the DB
- check and see if the trigger is enabled just before the query runs
- tip: if you're moving large amounts of data avoid triggers if you can (every case is different, just sayin) we usually disable/enable triggers from code when working with big data